# How to add pause/restart printing of text to console with keypress

Tags: rust, command-line-interface, ansi-escape, pause

The code below that reads a file and prints it to the console. I would like to add a "listener" function that will pause or restart the reader and the printing when a key is pressed, but I am new to Rust and don't know how to do that.

```
fn print_as_typed(filename: &str) {
  // Open the file and create a buffered reader
  let file = File::open(filename).unwrap();
  let reader = BufReader::new(file);

  // Create a handle to the standard output stream
  let mut stdout = std::io::stdout();

  // Clear the console screen
  print!("{}[2J{}[;H", 27 as char, 27 as char);

  // Loop over each line in the file
  for line in reader.lines() {
    // Loop over each character in the line and print it to the console
    for c in line.unwrap().chars() {
      stdout.write_all(c.encode_utf8(&mut [0; 4]).as_bytes()).unwrap();
      stdout.flush().unwrap();
      sleep(Duration::from_millis(50));
    }
    // Print a newline character to separate lines
    print!("\n");
  }
}
```

How can that be implemented?

Comment: Note: instead of `write_all` you can use the `write` macro: `write!(stdout, "{c}").unwrap()`